# Make div adjust to content size after content breaks to new line?

Tags: html, css

I have an inner `div` with `max-width: 50%`. The inner `div` contains content which may wrap to the next line. When the inner `div`'s contents wrap to the next line, due to the inner `div` being > 50% the width of its parent, the `div` continues to have 50% the width of its parent instead of having a width that matches its newly wrapped content.

Is there a way to have the inner `div`'s width shrink when the content wraps to a new line?

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">I_have_50%_width even_after_line_wraps</div>
</div
```

Comment: Shrink to what, exactly? Like I'm failing to see what width the inner div should be after wrapping.

Comment: Hey @Harangue, I'm hoping to have the inner div wrap to the text _after_ it breaks to the next line, instead of having a bunch of blank space to the right. Basically, as much padding to the right of the text as there is to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Update your inner class with the following css.

```
.inner {
 display: inline-block;
 background: blue;
 max-width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Adding `word-wrap: break word` property will break words inside your div to new line. You can learn more about the word-wrap property from [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)